# SQL search in the same order as requested and showing not found items

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to do a special query for SQL but I'm not able to get the wanted result.

My basic query is:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_NAME_1 in ('ABC1', 'ABC98', 'ABC97', 'ABC2', 'ABC3')
```

Imagine that the item 'ABC1' is not in the table. I would like my query to show it. In addition I would like that my query shows the items in the same order I asked (ABC1, ABC98, ABC97, and so on).

I attach an image where you'll understand better what I want.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: this most certainly should be done outside the database layer

Comment: Are you really looking to check the column names of your table?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I am using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an outer `join` or `union all`.  One method looks like:

```
select v.col1, . . .
from (select 'ABC1' as col1, 1 as ord union all
      select 'ABC98', 2  union all
      . . .
     ) left join
    TABLE_NAME t
    on t.column_name_1 = v.col1
order by ord;
```

The exact syntax for the list of values varies by database.  The above works for MySQL.  Oracle would require `from dual` in the subqueries.

Comment: MySQL also requires a `ORDER BY 
 FIELD(t.column_name_1, 'ABC1', 'ABC98', ....)` to enforce the sort order.. to complete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a table of the values to show along with their desired position. You can create this on the fly in the `FROM` clause. Then outer join your table:

```
select keys.name, t.column_name_2, t.column_name_3, t.column_name_4
from
(
  select 'ABC1' as name, 1 as sortkey
  union all
  select 'ABC98' as name, 2 as sortkey
  union all
  select 'ABC97' as name, 3 as sortkey
  union all
  select 'ABC2' as name, 4 as sortkey
  union all
  select 'ABC3' as name, 5 as sortkey
) as keys
left join table_name t on t.column_name_1 = keys.name
order by keys.sortkey;
```